# Datatable Addition to Dataset exception

Tags: c#, datatable

```
DataSet ds = DAL.GetData();
DataSet dsInvitee = null;

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
IEnumerable<DataRow> q1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(5).Take(10);

dsInvitee = new DataSet();

DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
dtNew.TableName = "DTInv";
dtNew = q1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
dsInvitee.Tables.Add(dtNew.Copy());
dsInvitee.AcceptChanges();

dtNew = null;
dtNew = new DataTable();
dtNew.TableName = "DTTags";
dtNew = ds.Tables[1].Copy();
dsInvitee.Tables.Add(dtNew.Copy());
```

I am getting error in the last line as "A DataTable named 'Table1' already belongs to this DataSet."... Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because of the line `dtNew = q1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`, because the [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) extension method:

> Returns a DataTable that contains copies of the DataRow objects, given an input IEnumerable object where the generic parameter T is DataRow.

This means that the table name of "DTInv" gets blown away as after the call to CopyToDataTable, `dtNew` no longer refers to the same `DataTable`. Move the `dtNew.TableName = "DTInv";` to **after** the call to `CopyToDataTable`:

```
DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
dtNew = q1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
dtNew.TableName = "DTInv";
dsInvitee.Tables.Add(dtNew.Copy());
dsInvitee.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Also, as @Daniel Hilgarth has mentioned, your second to last line is also at fault for pretty much the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the second to last row. You are overwriting the instance dtNew. Everything you did so far with that instance is lost and it is assigned a table from the original dataset and that's what you are adding to the data set in the last row...

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Daniel has said above, try swapping the order of the

```
dtNew.TableName = "DTTags";
```

and the

```
dtNew = ds.Tables[1].Copy();
```

lines around.